# AWS DMS: Table suspended

Tags: oracle, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

so I started to use AWS Data Migration Service to migrate a on-premise Oracle DB to AWS RDS Postgres. So far so good, the vast majority of tables get migrated (˜2000), two however fail. I enabled all available logging and debug options and can not get more then:

```
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:558678 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]D: Table schema 'my_schema.SRV_LOG_TABLE' is completed (oracle_endpoint_table.c:1880)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:564726 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]D: Cannot refresh source table (1) metadata [1021803] (endpointshell.c:3138)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:564726 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]E: Cannot refresh source table (1) metadata [1021803] (endpointshell.c:3138)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:584501 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]D: Start unload loop (oracle_endpoint_unload.c:346)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:584507 [TASK_MANAGER ]W: Table 'my_schema'.'SRV_LOG_TABLE' (subtask 1 thread 0) is suspended (replicationtask.c:2356)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:584540 [SOURCE_UNLOAD ]D: Unable to get table name for id '0' [1021802] (oracle_endpoint_unload.c:351)
18:56:12
2019-05-06T18:56:12:589667 [TASK_MANAGER ]D: Subtask #1 is going down (replicationtask_util.c:536)
```

I am not really sure what's going on and can not identify anything "special" about these tables (other table produces exactly the same log). Anyone experiences something similar and found a solution?

PS: Although I did enable the content log tables, nothing has been created there...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout....
Looks like a DDL was ran automaticaly, and messed definitions
https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/SOURCE-CAPTURE-E-Unable-to-get-table-definition-for-table-0/ta-p/1809603